# Is there a way to load gridviews individually on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, sqldatasource

I'm working on a monitoring webpage using C# & ASP.NET and I need to display data in multiple Gridviews with different data sources. Sometimes one of these data sources fails to connect or times out and as a result the page fails to load.

Is it possible to load the gridviews individually on page load (for example inside an update panel) so that if one of the gridviews fails to load, the rest of the page is not affected?

I tried wrapping the connection of the SqlDataSource\ and the binding of the Gridview inside a try/catch, but if the connection to the sql source fails, the whole page won't load.

I'm executing the following function on page load

```
protected void LoadReceivingState(string conString, string SelectCommand) 
    {
        string resultcode = "";
        try
        {
            SqlDataSource_ReceivingState.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[conString].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataSource_ReceivingState.SelectCommand = SelectCommand;
            SqlDataSource_ReceivingState.SelectCommandType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataSource_ReceivingState.DataBind();
            GridView_ReceivingState.DataSourceID = null;
            GridView_ReceivingState.DataSource = null;
            GridView_ReceivingState.DataSource = SqlDataSource_ReceivingState;
            GridView_ReceivingState.DataBind();
            GridView_ReceivingState.Visible = true;
            //PanelAppTracking.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            GridView_ReceivingState.Visible = false;
            
            resultcode = "code: " + ex.Number.ToString() + "Error: " + ex.Message.ToString();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert(resultcode);", true);
            
        }

        
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can probably do it with UpdatePanel as you mention but you need a specific problem with specific code for a real answer.

Comment: An easy approach would be to wrap the loading of the data sources in `try-catch` blocks and hide the gridview if an error occurs. In addition, the exception should at least be logged so you can analyze the failures later.